# Open in default browser exception

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

I'm using [`Eclipse`](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/keplersr1) to develop Java Desktop applications. The [`Desktop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class has a useful method called [`browse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse(java.net.URI)) which opens an URI in the system's default browser. My problem is that this feature isn't working anymore in `Eclipse` but still works fine outside of `Eclipse` e.g. when launching an executable `Jar` file containing the code.

Here's a short compilable example:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class OpenExample
{
    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws URISyntaxException, IOException
    {
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("https://www.google.com/"));
    }
}
```

I'm receiving the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to open https://www.google.com/. Error message: A device attached to the system is not functioning.

    at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.ShellExecute(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.browse(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Desktop.browse(Unknown Source)
    at OpenExample.main(OpenExample.java:10)
```

What could be the problem? Obviously the `Java` code is right and since it worked before, something must be broken in `Eclipse` or maybe even `Windows`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be related this this JDK bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8064934

I.e. there might be a real error occurring, but the JDK is reporting the wrong error code because of this bugs.

Comment: The problem is still wit the latest (1.8.0_112) jre

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.URI;

public class OpenExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "http://google.com";

        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) { // for windows
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(url));
        } else { // for linux
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            runtime.exec("/usr/bin/firefox -new-window " + url);
        }
    }
}
```

- try this Some times it depend upon OS as well .
- Check print Statement giving URL or not .

  **if it will work please give your review**

Comment: Desktop is supported since I'm running `Windows` therefore this code does the same thing as the one in my initial post. Testing also verifies this: Exception at `Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(url));`